# string issue with addslashes

Tags: php

I have a loop that builds a table with camera names.  In that table is a button:

```
<button id="editbutton" onClick='edit(this, "<?php echo addslashes($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>", "<?php echo addslashes($result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]); ?>")'>Edit</button>
```

What I want to do is accept special characters such as single quote, double quote and backslash because I pass this to a javascript function that does some extra stuff:

```
var edit = function(t, to, cameraname)
{

var mydiv = $("#editform");

if (mydiv.find("form").length) {
    mydiv.show();
} else {
    // fields
    var $myform = $("<form id='EditCameraForm' name='' method='post' action='" + to + "'></form>");
    var $myfieldset = $("<fieldset><legend>Edit camera settings</legend></fieldset>");
    var $mylabel = $("<label for='CameraName'>Camera name:&nbsp;</label>");
    var $myinput2 = js('<input/>').attr('size','25').attr('name','camera_name').attr('id','CameraName').val(cameraname);
...
}
```

My problem is `cameraname` is not escaping the special characters.  In another post I've been steered down the road of using `addslashes`.  Sounds good but I believe the problem is my string: `$result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]`.  I can do a simple test:

```
<?php $str="a's camera";
$str=addslashes($str);
echo $str; 
?>
```

This returns `a\'s camera` as expected.  But if I do:

```
<?php $str=$result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"];
$str=addslashes($str);
echo $str; 
?>
```

This just returns `a's camera`.  I'm sure I'm missing something brain dead here, why is this not being treated as a string with addslashes?

Note: magic_quotes_gpc is off

Comment: what is the original `$result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"];` value?

Comment: The value comes from a query to the database, basically whatever someone entered as their camera name.  In my test the string `a's camera`

Comment: Ok, but if addslashes is missing that single quote, it might not be a single quote..

Comment: Not sure I follow. If I echo `$result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"];` it returns `a's camera`. I've tried other characters like double quotes and backslash all with the same result.

Comment: try looking at the source. if it's really ' you should see ' there.

Comment: Oh...didn't even think about that. It's actually encoded. So `a'a` looks like `a&#039;a` and `a"a` looks like `a&quot;a`. Geez I forgot about my sanitize_input function which uses htmlspecialchars to begin with.  I guess I need to decode this in javascript.

Comment: check the method that writes to the db. is there anything like htmlentities()?

Comment: See my edited comment above. It looks like I have to find a better way to do this because I use `$data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` when the camera is first created for security reasons.  Is there a way to encode/decode all characters and not just some like htmlspecialchars?

Comment: you mean htmlspecialchars_decode()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, it is some other type of single quote, not `&#39;`.

For transfering data from php to js, `jsone_ncode` is the best option. It is good for just strings too.

Comment: I've tried json_encode as well and still have the same problem.  Something must be going on with the string.  Plus it is not just the single quote that is the problem. Double quotes or backslash give the same problem.

Comment: `json_encode` doesn't add slashes before single quotes — only double quotes are escaped. Try `echo ord($str[1]);` to see, what's whith this character.